# sql laravel count() делает запрос около 4 минут

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Если делая обычный запрос в базу данных
select count(*) from table where fields in ("30004","30005","30007")
Ответ в течение 0.9-1 секунды.
Если через Model::wherenIn(fields,[])->count()
ТО около 4 минуты

Пытался добавить ->select(DB::raw("count(*)")).

Смотрел запрос через toSql() все красиво,только выполняю сразу беда.

Получается переписывать нужно на DB?

Comment: сколько записей в таблице? И не совсем понятно зачем и на что переписывать, если вы не добились ни одним из способов улучшения производительности

Comment: В базе миллионы, по выборке на данный момент 60000.

Comment: Можно в принцепи переписать вручную, через builder, ,но хотелось бы через eloquent

Comment: вы мастер описания проблем. 1) дана такая то таблица (create table + индексы). 2) пример данныъ 2) строк столько то 4) запрос такой-то (в ide, консоли) 5) explain запроса 6) пхп код в ларавель такой-то 6) реальный выполняемый ларавелем код такой-то (лучше вообще отлоггировать все sql запросы выполняемые в рамках одного хттп запроса, а то еще окажается, что не в том месте проблему ищите)  8) как засекаете время выполнения через ларевель

Comment: Вас понял, попробую отпишусь